# Tool for drawing diagrams

Tags: gratis, drawing, charts, er-diagram, component-diagram

I am looking for a tool for drawing diagrams (sets diagrams, relations, etc) where the objects inside are high level objects like book, car, house, etc (looking like icons, or emoticons); rather than primitive objects like squares, circles.

Visio might be a close tool, but I am looking for a free tool, with smiley-like components.

Comment: operating system?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest taking a look at [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/):

- Free & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Has its own clip art
- Can import clip art/images to use those
- [Portable edition](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/) available so you can run from a USB key.

[image: Draw Screenshot with some clipart]

Comment: The page size is too small!

Comment: @Colas are you talking about the screenshot above, where I was also browsing the clipart which you can close when done, you  can also zoom the page, or about the actual physical page, on mine you just go to Format->Page and under paper format I can pick up to A0 which is a **big** piece of paper.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/):

- free and open source
- cross-platform
- supposed to be an open source Visio:

[image]

Comment: Note: Not the same as the `pencil` package in Ubuntu's repositories.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think that Microsoft Visio is the best by far in terms of number of features it contains but the website [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)  (formerly known as Diagram.ly) is pretty good:

- free
- a good amount of shapes available
- connection with Google Drive and a few other online services

[image]

Comment: Does any of them have clipart library to use?

Comment: @DanaWild I use external libraries like http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear and import images as needed.

Comment: Draw.io is no longer free: https://drawio-app.com/ ... or at least I'm uncertain about it. I sometimes cannot get to the drawing part.

Comment: @MartinThoma thanks, perhaps https://www.draw.io is freemium? I just tried and could make a simple diagram

Comment: Yes, when I clicked on your link it worked for me as well. But when I used my bookmark I couldn't get to the drawing option any longer. And it seems to be the same link. Very weird.

Answer (score 3):

[Dia](http://alternativeto.net/software/dia/) is a diagram creation program for Linux, Unix and Windows

> Dia is roughly inspired by the commercial Windows program 'Visio', though more geared towards informal diagrams for casual use.

[Diashapes](http://dia-installer.de/diashapes/index.html.en) is an external program to download Dia compatibles shapes from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I used Dia for years, but changed a while back to [Y-edit](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/).

It comes with some good built-in images, but what I really like is that you can add your own images and also assign them to section on the toolbar (houses, animals, etc).

When I don't have the correct icon to hand, I download a Creative Commons image, edit it and scale it to suit, then import it. That way I can re-use it in future diagrams.

Import your own data from an Excel® spreadsheet (.xls) or XML[image]

Create diagrams with ease via an intuitive user interface.
[image]

Automatically arrange your diagram elements.
[image]

Export bitmap and vector graphics as PNG, JPG, SVG, PDF, SWF
[image]