# Are there specific tools for drawing UML diagrams?

Tags: gratis, productivity, diagram, uml, design

Related to this [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9739/tool-for-drawing-diagrams), but different because that question is 8 years out of date.

I draw UML diagrams by hand or on PowerPoint, but they quickly become messy as I develop them.

Are there any specific tools that exist for drawing UML diagrams?

(I'd like the tool to be free to use.)

Comment: Sure there are such programs, but do you want only freeware or is comercial software also OK? Which Diagrams you need?

Comment: did you have a look at plantuml?

Comment: @convert I've updated the question to indicate I'd like the tool to be free to use!

Comment: Then I added a coresponding tag.

Answer (score 3):

[StarUML](https://staruml.io/) is a free UML tool. The declared goal of the project is to replace large, commercial applications such as Borlands Together or Rational Rose. StarUML is the world's first free UML tool, using a modified version of the GNU General Public License.

Answer (score 2):

One classic tool I've used is [Dia Diagramming Tool](http://dia-installer.de/), I can't vouch for it's relative usefulness compared to other suggestions but it is functional, fit for purpose and free.

Another tool you might not have considered is the text-based [Mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/classDiagram.html)

Mermaid is a text-based tool for generating various diagrams, not just Class diagrams. There's a bunch of integrations for editors/tools such as Jira/Github/vscode. Definitely worth a look if you prefer typing to clicking.

Answer (score 1):

[UMLet](https://www.umlet.com/) is a free, open-source UML tool with a simple user interface: draw UML diagrams fast, build sequence and activity diagrams from plain text, export diagrams to eps, pdf, jpg, svg, and clipboard, share diagrams using Eclipse, and create new, custom UML elements. UMLet runs standalone or as Eclipse plug-in on Windows, macOS and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[diagrams.net](https://www.diagrams.net/) is great. Free to use, and you can store your diagrams locally in your browser.

If you read their [about page](https://www.diagrams.net/about) you can see they're all about disrupting this industry, and their tool is really nice!